# DD4T - How to fetch nested embedded fields in Razor?

Tags: 2011, dd4t

My XML structure looks like this:

- links

  - title
  - image
  - internal_link (Component Link)

    - headline
    - type
    - section

I want to fetch the field `headline` of `internal_link`.

I am using the following code:

```
<div id="verticalNav">
   @if (Model.Component.Fields.ContainsKey("links")
   {
      foreach (var lnk in Model.Component.Fields["links"].EmbeddedValues)
      {
         if (lnk.ContainsKey("internal_link"))
         {
            foreach (var intlnk in lnk["internal_link"].LinkedComponentValues)
            {
               if (intlnk.Fields.ContainsKey("headline"))
               {
                  <p>intlnk.Fields["headline"].Value</p>
               }
            }
         }  
      }
   }
</div>
```

However, it's failing to check the condition `intlnk.Fields.ContainsKey("headline")`. Yet field `headline` has a value.

I increased the value of the `linklevels` to 4, but still it is not working. Did I miss anything?

Comment: The subject of your question mentions 'nested embedded fields', but your code indicates that you have one level of embedded fields ("links"), and a component link field ("internal_link") inside of that. Can you confirm that this is correct? Maybe you can post the relevant part of the XML?

Comment: Did you re-publish your components after changing the link level?

Comment: you are right robrtc,i missed to re-publish the component.But I cannot figure it out why we need to do that because components were published.

Comment: After any change in a Template or in the Component content, you need to publish these changes for them to appear on the delivery side. So you probably did make changes that hadn't been published, or maybe you tried publishing a Template which was still checked out (open in the Template Builder for example).

Answer (score 4):

The LinkLevels parameter in your TBB has to be set accordingly to include nested Component Links.

After any change in a Template or in the Component content, you will need to publish these changes for them to appear on the delivery side.

Since you mentioned you did make a change in the link levels, I'm assuming you haven't Published all Components using the Component Template you have changed the LinkLevels in, or maybe you tried Publishing a Template which was still checked out (open in the Template Builder for example). These are common causes for changes not to appear on the delivery side.